# Code Blocks Debugging "(no debugging symbols found)" and "Error creating process, error (193)" using GNU GCC Compiler and GNU gbd 6.8

Tags: c++, c, debugging, gcc, arduino-uno

I realize people have posted similar problems - But the answers haven't resolved my problem...or maybe I'm just not implementing the solution properly. I checked to make sure there are no spaces in the exe path. And I checked off `-g` in the project build options. I'm a newb and I'm hoping someone can look at the message below and give me some feedback about what could be going wrong-and what I can do to fix it.

Thanks!

---

```
Building to ensure sources are up-to-date
Selecting target: 
Arduino Uno
Adding source dir: C:\Arduino\TEST\
Adding source dir: C:\Arduino\TEST\
Adding file: C:\Arduino\TEST\build\TEST_uno.elf
Changing directory to: C:/Arduino/TEST/.
Set variable: PATH=.;C:\Users\Jack Skellington\Downloads\CodeBlocks\bin;C:\Users\Jack Skellington\Downloads\CodeBlocks;C:\WinAVR\utils\bin;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Ruby22-x64\bin
Starting debugger: C:\Users\Jack Skellington\Downloads\CodeBlocks\bin\gdb.exe -nx -fullname  -quiet  -args C:/Arduino/TEST/build/TEST_uno.elf
done
Registered new type: wxString
Registered new type: STL String
Registered new type: STL Vector
Setting breakpoints
(no debugging symbols found)
Debugger name and version: GNU gdb 6.8
Error creating process C:/Arduino/TEST/build/TEST_uno.elf, (error 193).
Debugger finished with status 0
```

Comment: Did you pass the `-g -Wall -Wextra` options to `gcc` or `g++` ? Show the compilation commands.

Comment: Is this done in the project build options - under the compiler settings tab?

Comment: I have no idea. Why don't you compile on the command line, or using a builder like `make` ? You don't need CodeBlocks (especially if you don't master it)....

Comment: Honestly I'm just looking for fast way to debug code I am writing for an arduino. I'm pretty new to programming in C/C++. If I compile using one of the options you suggested - what is the best way to debug the code?